# ListAdapter Mission Impossible? Combine ImageViews and Animations inside of one?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation, android-imageview

I have a list adapter where the images load with a rotating progress animation until they are fetched from the net. When I scroll down in the listView, it appears that the animation spins a previous image...this is a ***Very Weird*** and undesirable effect. The only thing that should be spinning is the progress animation.

I use a class called ImageLoader to asynchronously netfetch the images:

```
final int stub_id=R.drawable.progress;
public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView,int size)
{
    //Log.d("ImageLoader" , url);
    this.size=size;
    if(cache.containsKey(url)) {
        //If this works, then why do the OLD images still spin??
                    imageView.clearAnimation();
        //imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        //imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
    }
    else
    {
        rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.drawable.progress);
        rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        imageView.startAnimation(rotation);
        queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
        //imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        //imageView.setBackgroundResource(stub_id); 
    }
    Resources r = activity.getResources();
    int dip = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = dip;
    layoutParams.width = dip;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Now you might ask, what does queuePhoto do? This is the ONLY other place where the animation is started.

```
//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imageView;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
    public void run()
    {


        if(bitmap!=null) {
            imageView.clearAnimation();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else {
            imageView.clearAnimation();
            rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.drawable.progress);
            rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            imageView.startAnimation(rotation);
            //imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);

        }
    }
}
```

And now part of my list adapter's getView:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if( convertView == null ){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trending_item, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.img1 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.t_item_1);
            holder.img2 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.t_item_2);
            holder.img3 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.t_item_3);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }
        JSONObject t1= ts.get(1);
        if(t1 !=null) {
                holder.img1.setTag(t1.getString("image_small"));
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(t1.getString("image_small"), act, holder.img1,IMAGE_SIZE);
                holder.img1.setTag(TAG_T t1.getString("id"));
                holder.img1.setOnClickListener(ocl);
            } else {
                holder.img1.setImageDrawable(null);
                holder.img1.setBackgroundDrawable(null);    
                holder.img1.setTag(null);   
                holder.img1.setTag(TAG_T, null);
            }
```

**UPDATE**

I implemented JBM's proposed solution, but I was not able to make it work, he recommends running on the UI thread.

```
public class RemoteImageView extends ImageView implements RemoteLoadListener {

final int stub_id=R.drawable.progress;
int size;
private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
Animation rotation;
private File cacheDir;


public RemoteImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

public RemoteImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
    photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public RemoteImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public void displayRemoteImage(String url, Activity activity, int size)
{
    this.myUrl = url;
    this.size=size;
    Resources r = activity.getResources();
    int dip = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    LayoutParams layoutParams = this.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = dip;
    layoutParams.width = dip;
    this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    if(cache.containsKey(url)) {
        this.clearAnimation();
        setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
    }
    else
    {
        rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.drawable.progress);
        rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        this.startAnimation(rotation);
        queuePhoto(url, activity, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadSuccess(String url, Bitmap bmp) {
    if (url.equals(myUrl)) {
        setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } else {
        /* the arrived bitmap is stale. do nothing. */
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFail(String url) {
    if (url.equals(myUrl)) {
        setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(stub_id)).getBitmap());
    } else {
        /* the failed bitmap is stale. do nothing. */
    }
}
String myUrl;
private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
{
    //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
    photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
    }

    //start thread if it's not started yet
    if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
        photoLoaderThread.start();
}
PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

public void stopThread()
{
    photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
}

//stores list of photos to download
class PhotosQueue
{
    private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

    //removes all instances of this ImageView
    public void Clean(ImageView image)
    {
        for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
            if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                photosToLoad.remove(j);
            else
                ++j;
        }
    }
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
}


class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true)
            {
                //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                        photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                    }
                if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                {
                    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                        photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                    }
                    Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                    cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                    Object tag=photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                    if(tag!=null && ((String)tag).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                    }
                }
                if(Thread.interrupted())
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //allow thread to exit
        }
    }
}

PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView imageView;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
    public void run()
    {   
        if(bitmap!=null) {
            imageView.clearAnimation();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        else {
            imageView.clearAnimation();
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }
}
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    System.out.println("GET: " +url);
    if(url== null) {
        return null;
    }
    //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<size || height_tmp/2<size)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("ImageLoader",e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is race between `ImageView` and your `DisplayImage` function. As the list is scrolling up or down the rows get reused, so when a remote image arrives it often happens that its target view already belongs to a different row. The only reliable way of doing that is making you own class `RemoteImageView extends ImageView` which handles fetching the image internally. Then RemoteImageView can do proper synchronization.

Let your `queuePhoto` method take a `RemoteLoadListener` instead of ImageView, like this:

```
public interface RemoteLoadListener {
    void onLoadFail(String url);
    void onLoadSuccess(String url, Bitmap bmp);
}
```

Then make your `RemoteImageView` a `RemoteLoadListener` and do all the stuff internally:

```
public class RemoteImageView extends ImageView implements RemoteLoadListener {

    final int static stub_id=R.drawable.progress;
    public void displayImage(String url, Activity activity, int size)
    {
        myUrl = url;

        if(cache.containsKey(url)) {
            ...
            setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
        }
        else
        {
            ...
            imageView.startAnimation(rotation);
            queuePhoto(url, activity, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadSuccess(String url, Bitmap bmp) {
        if (url.equals(myUrl)) {
            setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else {
            /* the arrived bitmap is stale. do nothing. */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFail(String url) {
        if (url.equals(myUrl)) {
            setImageBitmap(placeholder);
        } else {
            /* the failed bitmap is stale. do nothing. */
        }
    }
}
```

So in your `getView` method you simply do this:

```
holder.img1.displayImage(t1.getString("image_small"), act, IMAGE_SIZE);
```

### UPDATE

Try first reducing complexity of the system. I've removed your photo queue and cache and replaced it with downloading the image from the web (this piece is based on your code). I didn't run this code, I just typed it. But it should give you a clear idea.

```
public class RemoteImageView extends ImageView implements RemoteLoadListener {

    public RemoteImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RemoteImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public void displayRemoteImage(String url, Activity activity, int size)
    {
        this.myUrl = url;
        this.size=size;
        Resources r = activity.getResources();
        int dip = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, size, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        LayoutParams layoutParams = this.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = dip;
        layoutParams.width = dip;
        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        {
            rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.drawable.progress);
            rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            this.startAnimation(rotation);
            queuePhoto(url, activity, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadSuccess(String url, Bitmap bmp) {
        if (url.equals(myUrl)) {
            setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else {
            /* the arrived bitmap is stale. do nothing. */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFail(String url) {
        if (url.equals(myUrl)) {
            setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(stub_id)).getBitmap());
        } else {
            /* the failed bitmap is stale. do nothing. */
        }
    }
    String myUrl;

    private void queuePhoto(final String url, final RemoteLoadListener listener)
    {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                //from web
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                InputStream is = null;
                OutputStream os = null;
                try {
                    is = new URL(url).openStream();
                    os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                    bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                } catch (Exception ex){
                    bitmap = null;
                } finally {
                    if (is != null) try { is.close(); } catch (IOException e) { /* ignore */ };
                    if (os != null) try { os.close(); } catch (IOException e) { /* ignore */ };
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    listener.onLoadSuccess(url, result);
                } else {
                    listener.onLoadFail(url);
                }
            };
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

PS: Note the `try - finally` block when working with streams.

Comment: i'm implementing now to verify. instead of imageView.startAnimation, I think you mean this.startAnimation ya?

Comment: Sorry, I implemented an ImageView with a background loading thread, but this approach does not prevent any race conditions

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss `url.equals(myUrl)` check? This is the key part. And, of course, `onLoadSuccess`/`onLoadFail` callbacks must be called on UI thread. If you do everything right it WILL work, GUARANTEED.

Comment: The code of  my implementation has been added to body of this question.

Comment: You still have race in this line:
`BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
`
In the `BitmapDisplayer` you still manipulate the bitmap instead letting the RemoteImageView do its job.

Comment: So you recommend I should do what with the BitmapDisplayer?

Comment: You just don't need it. `BitmapDisplayer` does the job which is done in the `onLoadSuccess`/`onLoadFail` methods, but because it does it from outside it's out of sync. Instead, you should call `onLoadSuccess` in the place where you'd call `BitmapDisplayer`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I spend more than one day on it and at last i found a simple solution.
I just remove the "if else" condition on getView() function on the class extends BaseAdapter as follows...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trending_item, null);
    holder=new ViewHolder();
    holder.img1 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.t_item_1);
    holder.img2 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.t_item_2);
    holder.img3 = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.t_item_3);
    JSONObject t1= ts.get(1);
    if(t1 !=null) {
            holder.img1.setTag(t1.getString("image_small"));
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(t1.getString("image_small"), act, holder.img1,IMAGE_SIZE);
            holder.img1.setTag(TAG_T t1.getString("id"));
            holder.img1.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        } else {
            holder.img1.setImageDrawable(null);
            holder.img1.setBackgroundDrawable(null);    
            holder.img1.setTag(null);   
            holder.img1.setTag(TAG_T, null);
        }
```